# Printing function in javascript is not printing textbox values

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to print an HTML table with textboxes take their values from another function. but it shows nothing in the Preview . 
This is the full Code :

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function bill() { //Bill
var PriceTest = document.getElementById("Val");
var Quantity = document.getElementById("Quan");
var price = document.getElementById("total");
price.value = PriceTest.value * Quantity.value ;

var tq = document.getElementById("TQuantity");
tq.value = Quantity.value;
} 

function printData() {
    var TablePrint = document.getElementById("TestTable");
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(TablePrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print(); // Printing the Bill
}

</script>
<body>
<form>
<table border="1">
<input type="number" id="Quan" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0"/>
<input type="text" value="100000" class="TextStyle" id="Val"/>
<input type="button" class="BuyButton" name="Buy" Value="Calc" onclick="bill()"/></table>
<br/><br/>
<table id="TestTable" border="1">
<input type="text" id="total" class="TextStyle" onfocus="this.blur();">
<input type="text" id="TQuantity" class="TextStyle" onfocus="this.blur();">
</table>
<input type="button" value="Print This" onclick="printData()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing newWin.document.write(TablePrint.outerHTML); to newWin.document.write(TablePrint.innerHTML);

Comment: when I switched to {{ newWin.document.write(TablePrint.innerHTML); }}
it said (Preview Failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be printing input fields.
This is an example with paragraph tags.

(You should also tidy up the code a bit :)

```html
<html>

<head></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bill() { //Bill
  var PriceTest = document.getElementById("Val");
  var Quantity = document.getElementById("Quan");
  var price = document.getElementById("total");
  price.innerHTML = PriceTest.value * Quantity.value ;
  
  var tq = document.getElementById("TQuantity");
  tq.innerHTML = Quantity.value;
  } 
  
  function printData() {
      var TablePrint = document.getElementById("TestTable");
      var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table th, table td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;' +
        'padding;0.5em;' +
        '}' +
        '</style>';
      htmlToPrint += TablePrint.outerHTML;
      newWin = window.open("");
      newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
      newWin.print(); // Printing the Bill
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form>
    <table border="1">
      <input type="number" id="Quan" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" />
      <input type="text" value="100000" class="TextStyle" id="Val" />
      <input type="button" class="BuyButton" name="Buy" Value="Calc" onclick="bill()" />
    </table>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table id="TestTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p id="total"></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p id="TQuantity"></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Print This" onclick="printData()" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: it is just a small example with the functions I have problem with ,,, It's not an official version ;)  

but when I print this it only show the values without the table ,,  what if I wanted to print the table like it shows in the browser with values in it ?

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer :(

Comment: Hey! I edited the above example. And yes, I understand it's just an prototype! Make sure you also tidy up my code :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is because your table markup is incorrect. tr is the tag for a table row, and td is the tag for the table data (cell) within that row.

```
<table id="TestTable" border="1">
<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="total" class="TextStyle" onfocus="this.blur();">
<input type="text" id="TQuantity" class="TextStyle" onfocus="this.blur();">
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I try them with <tr> <td> markup ... but it's now only shows the table borders in print preview ,,, I need to print the values

Comment: is there any reason you have input fields for total and TQuantity?  If you instead use <span>, for instance you can just set the innerText.  This will suit your purposes, and you won't need to 'blur' to prevent user input

Answer (score 0):

Your script is correct, but looks like your html markup isn't valid.  You would end up with the textboxes outside of the table with your current implementation (at least in Chrome) other browsers might omit the invalid markup.  You will need tr/td.

```
<table id="TestTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="total" class="TextStyle" onfocus="this.blur();">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="TQuantity" class="TextStyle" onfocus="this.blur();">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I try them with <tr> <td> markup ... but it's now only shows the table borders in print preview ,,, I need to print the values